# Ask for 2 values using same Scanner

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
System.out.println("Inserte la marca de la tele.");

                    String marca = sn.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Introduce el número de la televisión.");

                    int numero = sn.nextInt();
```

I want to save each input in their variable. But the program show this:

[image: Console]

How can i wait for the input before Java ask the next one?

Thanks!

Comment: Debes de traducir a español. Este no es el foro de ingles.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial de este sitio es el español, por lo que puede traducir su pregunta o rehacerla en [so].

Comment: Al compilar esa parte del código trabaja bien. Pide un dato y espera a que sea ingresado para solicitar el otro. No hay problema con ello. Tal vez tengas algo diferente en la declaración del objeto del Scanner. Lo correcto es lo siguiente: Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);